# "locale" information missing in Alexa HouseholdList event request / How to get multi language support in event handler?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have successfully integrated the Alexa.HousholdListEvents in my node.js AWS lambda based skill. Now I am trying to use language translation as for usual Intents / Requests.

Unfortunately in the HousholdListEvent the "request" does not contain locale information and instead of a translated string I am getting just the identifier repeated when using t(). See example below. I cannot get the locale information from the received event and would have to fall back to english which is blocking me from starting skill the certification process.

If you need further information - feel free to ask. I am more than happy to provide more details if needed.

Any advice? Help is appreciated!

Why do I have no locale information as part of the event?

Why is t() not working as expected (just like for normal intents)?

How could I translate in the event handler based on the origin locale?

My event request:

```
"request": {
    "type": "AlexaHouseholdListEvent.ItemsCreated",
    "requestId": "4a3d1715-e9b3-4980-a6eb-e4047ac40907",
    "timestamp": "2018-03-12T11:20:13Z",
    "eventCreationTime": "2018-03-12T11:20:13Z",
    "eventPublishingTime": "2018-03-12T11:20:13Z",
    "body": {
        "listId":        "YW16bjEuYWNjb3VudC5BRVlQT1hTQ0MyNlRQUU5RUzZITExKN0xNUUlBLVNIT1BQSU5HX0lURU0=    ",
        "listItemIds": [
            "fbcd3b22-7954-4c9a-826a-8a7322ffe57c"
        ]
    }
},
```

My translation usage:

```
this.t('MY_STRING_IDENTIFIER')
```

My result (in the ItemsCreated event handler):

```
MY_STRING_IDENTIFIER
```

Expected result (as for other requests):

```
"This is my translated text"
```

Comment: According to https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/develop-skills-in-multiple-languages.html#h2-code-changes the locale should be part of the request. Why is this not the case in my event? How can I get the locale information?

Comment: Meanwhile commented by Amazon: "Thanks for posting your question to the forum. Sorry it took a while to get a feedback. We will investigate this issue further and keep you posted of any developments."

Comment: List API FAQ information:

How should the developer handle localization of the To-Do and Shopping lists? The default lists (To-Do and Shopping List) list_id values are base-64 encoded strings with these formats: -TASK for the to-do list -SHOPPING_LIST for the shopping list Developers can base64 decode the list_id value and look for the specified string at the end. This string is constant and agnostic to localization.

Comment: According to Amazon it is as intended. If anybody runs into the same problem, please support the idea so that we may get the locale property anytime soon:

https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote/suggestions/34621093-provide-locale-property-in-event-skillevent-list